# Нужно сделать аудиоплеер

Tags: javascript, html

здравствуйте нужно для этого плеера сделать раздельные элементы управления то есть чтобы при нажатии кнопки начать начинало играть, не смущайтесь что 
написано videojs, это спицальная библиотека и элементы управления сделать нужно именно на ней

```
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.15/video.js"> 
             </script>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.15/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div id="melody-1" class="button" data-src="1.mp3">Начать</div>
    <audio id="my-player" class="video-js" controls >
      <source id="my-spanish-audio-track" src="1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var player = videojs('my-player');

    // Create a track object.
    var track = new videojs.AudioTrack({
      id: 'my-spanish-audio-track',
      kind: 'translation',
      label: 'Spanish',
      language: 'es'
    });

    // Add the track to the player's audio track list.
    player.audioTracks().addTrack(track);
    </script>

>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете запустить видео все теми же средствами javascript. Для этого стоит повесить на кнопку обработчик события, который выполняет метод play() для видео.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('melody-1');
var video = document.getElementById('my-player');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  video.play();
}
```